# JavaScript Zero Bitwise Left-Shift and Right-Shift Equivalent in Python?

Tags: javascript, python, bit-manipulation, rounding, floor

In JavaScript, we can use bitwise left-shift and right-shift operators to truncate a float and round it down to the nearest integer.

Example:

```
console.log(2.667 << 0); //outputs 2
console.log(2.667 >> 0); //outputs 2
```

These bitwise operators also do the same thing:

```
console.log(2.667 | 0); //outputs 2
console.log(0 | 2.667); //outputs 2
console.log(~~2.667); //outputs 2
```

In Python, however, the same operations return errors.

Is there any equivalent in Python -- using bitwise operators? Or must I use int() and floor division to achieve what I'm looking for?

Comment: There are bitwise operators but you can't bitwise shift a float like that... Javascript has a lot of non-standard behaviour. What you want is `round`, `floor`, or `int`, depending on your context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just cast the `float` to an int `int(2.667)` it will always floor/truncate the float once the float is non negative if you have negative numbers you  do want to floor not just truncate use math.floor .

```
In [7]: int(2.667 )
Out[7]: 2

In [22]: from math import floor

In [23]: int(floor(-2.667 )) # just floor(-2.667 ) using python3
Out[23]: -3
```

Answer (score 1):

Bitwise operators don't work on python floats.  In fact, JS is the only language where I might expect that to work...  Frankly, the fact that they work on JS numbers is probably an artifact of the fact that JS doesn't actually have an *integer* type...

If you call `int` on your `float` and then use the bitwise operators in python everything should work out the same.  e.g.

```
>>> int(2.667) << 0
2
```

Of course, if all you are trying to do is to truncate a float, you can just call `int` on it and all should be right with the world.